# DLink DIR-635 Wireless Connection Problem

Tags: router, d-link

I cannot connect to my dlink via wireless connection.
The problem has started recently. At first, the internet connection was getting slower and slower, and at some point in needed to restart the router. I could reconnect to the router easily, but not now.

Today, after restarting the router I simply cannot see the my wireless network. It's no longer in network list. I tried resetting the router, but still no luck. If I'll keep restarting the router, randomly I can see it in the list of connections, but the signal strength is so weak that I cannot connect. And then it simply disappears from the list.

Is there any chance to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might:

- check your antenna positioning
- ensure you are not utilizing a manufacturer/factory default SSID (e.g. linksys)
- ensure you are not utilizing a manufacturer/factory default wifi channel

Comment: the antenna is really close to my laptop.

Comment: How do I check the SSID, and WIFI channel?

Comment: Through the wireless settings within the web management interface.

Comment: Checked, and no, I use custom SSID, and wifi channel

Comment: Then you might look into verifying the performance of the wireless NAT router with another wireless device. If another wireless device works fine, then you have a probably broken (1st) device otherwise your wireless NAT router is probably broken. Or see if your wireless devices can connect to a different wireless network successfully.